# Mailkit IMAP gmail - how to send ? online Doumentation does not show how to send in examples

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

How do you send and email using Imapclient() ?

Using the examples on this page:
[Mimekit Documentation](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Introduction.htm)

I can't seem to find the method used to send and email once logged into IMAP and created the message.
Installed via Nuget and installed latest release
Have added this to my code:

```
using MimeKit;
using MailKit;
using MailKit.Search;
using MailKit.Security;
using MailKit.Net.Imap;
```

And references to Mailkit and Mimekit dll's.
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMAP is only for reading mail, it cannot be used for sending mail.

To send mail, you need to use the SmtpClient.

Comment: Thank you kindly ! For some reason I had gotten mixed up with SMTP